# Jquery menu - adding return function to another function (which does not normally return anything)

Tags: jquery, function, menu, return

I am very 3 weeks new to jquery and have been thrust into it at work (time pressure). I have searched but have not found any answers since I may not know to how to *word* the search.

Ok here goes:

I am using filamentgroup.com 's menu drop system located at http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/menus/flat.php

I call the function like this in my file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#lbOptionsButton').menu({ 
        content: $('#lbOptionsMenu').html() 
    }); 
});
```

In the (script src) fg.menu.js file, there is a section with:

```
this.chooseItem = function(item){
    menu.kill();
    // edit this for your own custom function/callback:
    $('#menuSelection').text($(item).text());   
    location.href = $(item).attr('href');
};
```

However, I do not want to write my function in that code. I'd like for it to simply return $(item). Also how would I call it so I can use $(item) in any other function I write? i.e. ajax, etc.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write your function inside that code block, then how about just *calling* **your function** from there, and then defining your function wherever  you want. So,

```
this.chooseItem = function(item){
menu.kill();
// edit this for your own custom function/callback:
$('#menuSelection').text($(item).text());   
location.href = $(item).attr('href');
MyFunction($(item));
```

};

Isn't that what you wan't???

Comment: Thanks for the response. Not really - I just want to have it return the result outside so I can manipulate that result in my other functions. It's a menu system, but I want to be able to use it not just for href. I basically want to not keep writing code in the menu jquery file, if I need new menu functions. Hope this clarifies!